# Photos Framework - How to tell where an asset came from (source)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, alassetslibrary

Back in Beta 2 I wrote an app to get familiar with the iOS 8 Photos framework. It displayed images in a UICollectionView with some text on each cell which displayed the source of the image (iTunes, iCloud, Photo Stream, Camera Roll, etc...). I honestly can't remember if that was for a single Asset or a Collection. My goal here is to list it for each asset.

Well that code I wrote is long gone and I can't seem to find anything in the header files about this. Grepping for those terms brings up PHPhotoLibrary.h +30, but it's just a comment. I see some info in PhotoTypes.h +56 for PHCollectionSubtype that seems related, but that's for collections. I'm only interested in Assets.

Was this removed or am I possibly overlooking something?

Comment: Any luck with this? Having the same issue at the moment.

Comment: I'm afraid not. I'm using 8.1 but the only relevant call I can find is: extern NSString *const PHImageResultIsInCloudKey NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0); in PHImageManager.h